# how to load a 32-bit constant starting at memory address 0x300

Tags: assembly, riscv

I have to store the hex 0x1234ABCD into a register s0 that starts at memory address 0x300?

```
lui s0, 0x1234B
addi s0, s0, 0xFFFFFBCD
?????
```

I expect to have stored in s0 0x1234ABCD so then I can manipulate each address as such: address 0 holds 0x12, address 1 holds 0x34, address 2 holds 0xAB, address 3 holds 0xCD

Comment: The low 12 bits are signed-negative, so you'll need to offset the high 20 bits by 1.  Look at how an assembler does it by assembling `li s0, 0x1234ABCD`.  (Use an assembler + disassembler, or a simulator with a GUI like RARS that can show you the assembled instructions. Or look at compiler output on https://godbolt.org/ for a function that just returns a constant.)

Comment: Bytes in registers don't have addresses.  You can right-shift and AND to extract 8-bit fields, but there is no "address" involved unless you stored to memory and used `lb` to access parts of the word.  (Which would then involve memory endianness.)  This is a totally separate issue from creating the value in a register in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `addi` the `0xBCD` part.

`addi` allows for a 12-bit immediate, and so `0xBCD` fits — however, it is a signed 12-bit immediate fields, so the value added will be `0xFFFFFBCD`.

Hence, the `lui` should offset the 20-bit value `0x1234A` by +1, becoming `0x1234B`, so that the effective -1 in the upper 20 bits of the sign extended `addi` will be cancelled out.